# ghc shared binary compiling gives -fPIC error for standard libraries

Tags: haskell, compilation

I want to build shared object (node.js addon) written in Haskell.

Command to compile:

```
cabal exec -- \
   ghc -cpp -pgmc gcc -optc-std=c++0x -optP-lpthread -O2 -threaded \
   -shared -no-hs-main -fPIC -o myaddon.node \
   -I. -I/usr/include/node/ -L. -lstdc++ -lpthread -lHSrts-ghc7.8.3 \
   hsbracket.c node.cc myaddon.hs
```

I understand that all Haskell libraries should be compiled with -fPIC option:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/ghc-7.8.3/binary-0.7.1.0/libHSbinary-0.7.1.0.a(Get__14.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Does it mean that base libraries are compiled without -fPIC option and I should compile everything by myself (by hacking cabal bootstrap.sh script)?

***Edit (Jan, 4):***

helloWorld.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Foreign.C
hsHelloWorld = newCString "Hello from Haskell"
foreign export ccall "hsHelloWorld" hsHelloWorld :: IO CString
main = return ()
```

nodehs.cc:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <nodehs_stub.h>

using namespace v8;

Handle<Value> wrapHelloWorld(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  return scope.Close(String::New( (char *)hsHelloWorld() ));
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set( String::NewSymbol("helloWorld"),
    FunctionTemplate::New(wrapHelloWorld)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(nodehs, Init)
```

hsbracket.c (very standard):

```
#include <HsFFI.h>
static void my_enter(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void my_enter(void) {
  static char *argv[] = { "nodehs.node", 0 }, **argv_ = argv;
  static int argc = 1;
  hs_init(&argc, &argv_);
}
static void my_exit(void) __attribute__((destructor));
static void my_exit(void) { hs_exit(); }
```

compiling command:

```
ghc -shared -fPIC -o nodehs.node  -I. -L. -lstdc++ -lHSrts-ghc7.8.4 \
 -I/node-v0.10.35/src/             \
 -I/node-v0.10.35/deps/v8/include/ \
 -I/node-v0.10.35/deps/uv/include  \
 nodehs.cc hsbracket.c helloWorld.hs
```

result:

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.8.4/base-4.7.0.2/libHSbase-4.7.0.2.a(Base__114.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `stg_bh_upd_frame_info' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.8.4/base-4.7.0.2/libHSbase-4.7.0.2.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

With `-dynamic` everything works but links all haskell libraries dynamically.

**How can I compile haskell libraries statically into addon?**

For exact same environment and testing I add Dockerfile (`docker build -t compile-node . && docker run -v /home/me/nodehs:/src:rw compile-node`)

```
FROM debian:wheezy

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install make curl bzip2 unzip gzip libgmp-dev zlib1g-dev

RUN curl -s http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35.tar.gz | tar xz
RUN curl -s http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/ghc-7.8.4-x86_64-unknown-linux-deb7.tar.bz2 |     tar xj
RUN curl -s http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install-1.18.0.5/cabal-install-1.18.0.5.tar.gz | tar xz

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN cd ghc-* && ./configure && make install
ENV EXTRA_BUILD_OPTIONS "--enable-executable-dynamic --enable-shared --ghc-options='-fPIC --dynamic-too'"
RUN cd cabal-* && ./bootstrap.sh --global
RUN cabal update

WORKDIR /src/

# first ghc command is needed to make helloWorld_stub.h
CMD ghc helloWorld.hs && \
  ghc -shared -fPIC -o nodehs.node \
  -I. -I/node-v0.10.35/src/ -I/node-v0.10.35/deps/v8/include/ -I/node-v0.10.35/deps/uv/include \
  -L. -lstdc++ -lHSrts-ghc7.8.4 \
  nodehs.cc hsbracket.c helloWorld.hs \
  && node -e "console.log(require('./nodehs.node').helloWorld())'"
```

Comment: Including your myaddon.hs file would help others help you. Are you able to add it to your question?

Comment: If you tell me how it is helpful I can create minimal version (with only one file). At the moment it is 22KB depending on 33 other .hs files.

Comment: I'd recommend instead trying to simplify the process in the extreme; get a "hello, world"-style dummy module to work with Node.js first so that you know that it's nothing with your code. If that still doesn't work without the base libraries being recompiled, then so be it.

Comment: Solution is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815467/haskell-dynamic-library