# Creating a Foreign Library in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've spent about a day now all over the documentation and Google, and can't seem to figure out a reasonable way to do dynamic foreign libraries in Haskell.

It's fairly easy to write a static library that gets compiled into a C or C++ program. However, creating a dynamic library using, from what I gather, the normal way (ghc -dynamic -shared -fPIC) causes runtime errors when calling hs_init (undefined symbols in libHSghc-prim). If I manually link libHSrts with the -l flag, everything works as intended. But doing it this way would require me to distribute all of the base Base Haskell libraries with my program. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815467/haskell-dynamic-library), which implies I could recompile GHC and then statically link everything to resolve my linker issues, but I would like to avoid needing a custom build of GHC if possible.

What am I doing wrong? Executables can be easily built without needing to distribute the entire runtime, so it's odd to me that I'm having so much trouble doing the same but as a library