# How do I recompile GHC with -fPIC?

Tags: haskell, shared-libraries, dockerfile, ghc

*Introduction: I'm actually trying to build a shared-library written in Haskell that compatible with C (could be used from C code without knowing it is written in Haskell), but I want all Haskell dependencies being statically linked, for now I can only dynamically link all dependencies (for every packages including "base" and "ghc-prim" packages. This experiment presented [here](https://github.com/unclechu/haskell-experiment-shared-library-for-c-application).*

I tried to solve that by writing [Dockerfile](https://github.com/unclechu/haskell-experiment-shared-library-for-c-application/blob/228b652f900c106ebdcde52b842a2fe090a47867/docker/ghc-with-fpic/Dockerfile) where I build GHC 8.2.2 from scratch with replaced *mk/build.mk* file with [this contents](https://github.com/unclechu/haskell-experiment-shared-library-for-c-application/blob/228b652f900c106ebdcde52b842a2fe090a47867/docker/ghc-with-fpic/my-build.mk) (I just did kinda the same I saw in different stack overflow issues like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815467/haskell-dynamic-library/28131655#28131655)) but when I try to link with `--make -static -shared -fPIC` I get a lot of similar errors about linking "ghc-prim", example of last one:

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /ghc-8.2.2-fpic/lib/ghc-8.2.2/ghc-prim-0.5.1.1/libHSghc-prim-0.5.1.1.a(Classes.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'stg_ap_0_fast' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
```

What should I actually do to build GHC with -fPIC and link my library with static Haskell dependencies?

`Dockerfile` forked from `debian:stretch`, here is quote of last most important part of it:

```
# ... apt-get update ... installing build-essential and other stuff ...

# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28131655/774228
# for info about customizations in 'build.mk'
COPY my-build.mk /my-build.mk

RUN mkdir /compile && cd /compile \
    && wget https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.2/ghc-8.2.2-src.tar.xz \
    && tar -xvf ghc-8.2.2-src.tar.xz \
    && rm ghc-8.2.2-src.tar.xz \
    && cd ghc-8.2.2/ \
    && ./configure --prefix=/ghc-8.2.2-fpic --disable-library-profiling --enable-shared \
    && cp /my-build.mk mk/build.mk \
    && make install \
    && cd /usr/local/bin \
    && ls /ghc-8.2.2-fpic/bin/ | xargs -I{} ln -s /ghc-8.2.2-fpic/bin/{}
```

And here is whole `my-build.mk` file:

```
SRC_HC_OPTS          = -H64m -O
EXTRA_HC_OPTS        = -fPIC
SRC_CC_OPTS          = -fPIC -O
GhcStage1HcOpts      = -fasm -O0
GhcStage2HcOpts      = -fasm -O0
GhcLibHcOpts         = -fasm -O2
GhcLibWays           = v dyn
DYNAMIC_GHC_PROGRAMS = YES
DYNAMIC_BY_DEFAULT   = NO
SplitObjs            = NO
HADDOCK_DOCS         = NO
BUILD_DOCBOOK_HTML   = NO
BUILD_DOCBOOK_PS     = NO
BUILD_DOCBOOK_PDF    = NO
V                    = 1
LATEX_DOCS           = NO
HSCOLOUR_SRCS        = NO
BeConservative       = YES
```

Comment: This is a good question but I think you're unlikely to attract a good answer here (GHC internals are very complex, esp. wrt compiling GHC itself in a non-standard way). I would suggest you post on the [ghc-devs mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/ghc-devs)

Comment: user2407038, I did it but for now with no success: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2017-December/015251.html